# Show that $1+5^n + 5^{2n} + 5^{3n} + 5^{4n}$ is never prime for n > 0 integer

Tags: number-theory

Show that $1+5^n + 5^{2n} + 5^{3n} + 5^{4n}$ is never prime for n > 0 integer

Trying cases on a computer I can see that the equation is divisible by 11 when $n \neq 5^k$. That's easy to prove if you write the sum as a fraction using the fact that the series is geometric.

Is there a more general way to solve the problem, one which includes a solution for $n=5k$ and doesn't require ansatz?

edit: $ n = 5k$ not $ n = 5^k $

Comment: Will expressing the number is base $5$ help ?

Comment: Is that hint? I thought of that but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: I solved it for $n$ odd, if we can combine that with your result we'd be done.

Comment: Can you show why it $n=5^k$ is needed? I could only show $n=5k$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Got it now. I deleted my comments.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Should be n = 5k

Comment: Oh ok :)${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case $1:n=2k$

Then our sum is $\frac{5^{10k}-1}{5^{2k}-1}=\frac{(5^{5k}-1)(5^{5k}+1)}{5^{2k}-1}$. Since the denominator is smaller than each of the factors we conclude the number is not prime.

Case $2: n=2k+1$

Let $a=5^{2k+1}$ and notice $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4=(a^2+3a+1)^2-5a(a+1)^2$.

Since $a=5^{2k+1}$ this is equal to: $(a^2+3a+1)^2-5^{2k+2}(a+1)^2=(a^2+3a+1)^2-(5^{k+1}(a+1))^2$

We recognize this as a difference of squares and obtain:

$((a^2+3a+1)-5^{k+1}(a+1))(a^2+3a+1)+5^{k+1}(a+1))$.

It is very easy to see the first factor is greater than $1$.

Comment: How did you obtain the initial expression in  the second case?